# cout a stringstream but print a pointer

Tags: c++, c++03

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class TestLog: public std::stringstream
{
        public:
                ~TestLog()
                {
                        cout << (str()) << endl; // Why does this print an address ?
                }
};

int main()
{
        TestLog() << "Hello World!"; //test 1 print an address
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "Hello World!";
        cout << (ss.str()) << endl; //test 2 print a string

        return 0;
}
```

And the output:

> 0x401b90
>
> Hello World!

Compiler info :

> g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)

In my opinion,
(a)the str() method of std::stringstream return a string.
(b)std::cout is an object of std::ostream.
So both of the two test will call the same operator funtion of ostream and print same "Hello world".
But test 1 print an address , test 2 print the correct "Hello world".
What wrong with me ? Thanks.

Comment: [can't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/x6C0v3XtW00OToKY)

Comment: Which compiler are you using ?

Comment: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/6kdI2E) prints correct results too.

Comment: g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)

Comment: [There we go](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QwSPL1PdLvm2XW0r). The behaviour arises when compiling as C++03. I added the tag for you.

Comment: Thank you. I test it with Vs ,and both output are "Hello world".

Answer (score 6):

`ss << "Hello World!";` is resolved to a call to the following overload ([#2 on this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2)):

```
template <class Traits>
std::basic_ostream<char, Traits> &std::operator << (
    std::basic_ostream<char, Traits> &os, char const *s
);
```

This overload decays the string literal into a `char const *`, then prints it.

To stir the mud, we can try the following snippet:

```
TestLog tl;
tl << "Hello World!";
```

This one will *also* resolve to the overload above, and print `Hello World!`. That is because `tl` is an lvalue which can bind to the first parameter that is a non-`const` lvalue reference.

In your example, `TestLog()` is an rvalue -- this overload cannot match! Thus another overload is chosen instead ([#7 here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)):

```
std::basic_ostream &std::basic_ostream::operator << (void const *value);
```

This one is a member function overload, and has been inherited from `std::stringstream`. Even though you can't bind a non-`const` reference to an rvalue, you *can* call non-`const` member functions on an rvalue. So this overload is a valid match, and it is chosen -- printing the address of the literal as if it were any old pointer.

C++11 brought a new overload to solve this issue, visible at [#3 here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2):

```
template <class CharT, class Traits, class T>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits> &operator << (
    basic_ostream<CharT, Traits> &&os, T const &value
);
```

`T const &` matches the literal's `char const[N]` type perfectly, so it is ranked higher than the `void const *` overload. The rvalue reference as first parameters binds to the temporary just fine.

Named rvalue references are considered lvalues, so this function can then call `os << value;` again to trampoline back into the overload set for an lvalue stream. Thus, in C++11 and above, both lines print `Hello World!`.